# if(isset($_POST['btn-save'])) doesn't return true

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Yep, this old chesnut I'm afraid. I've read through a lot of the previous answers to this question but I cannot get into this if statement even though 'btn-save' is definitely set as the name attribute on my submit button.

I'm using the code from this tutorial to post form data to my database: http://www.phpzag.com/ajax-registration-script-with-php-mysql-and-jquery/

My site structure is like this:

```
    - root
        - public_html
            - js
                app.js
        register.php
        db_connect.php
        form_page.php
```

My register.php file looks like this and I've added an echo inside the if statement:

```
    <?php
    include_once("db_connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['btn-save'])) {
    echo "in if";
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
    $address_1 = $_POST['address_1'];
    $address_2 = $_POST['address_2'];
    $address_3 = $_POST['address_3'];
    $city_town = $_POST['city_town'];
    $county = $_POST['county'];
    $post_code = $_POST['post_code'];
    $entrant_type = $_POST['entrant_type'];
    $chosen_store = $_POST['chosen_store'];
    $chosen_charity = $_POST['chosen_charity'];
    $agree_terms = $_POST['agree_terms'];
    $sql = "SELECT user_email FROM tbl_big_challenge_registrations WHERE user_email='$email_id'";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset);      
    if(!$row['user_email']){    
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_big_challenge_registrations('uid', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_email', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'address_3', 'town_city', 'county', 'postcode', 'entrant_type', 'crew_store', 'charity', 'agree_terms') VALUES (NULL, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_id', '$address_1', '$address_2', '$address_3', '$city_town', '$county', '$post_code', '$entrant_type', '$chosen_store', '$chosen_charity', 'agree_terms', NULL)";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn)."qqq".$sql);            
        echo "registered";
    } else {                
        echo "1";    
    }
}

?>
```

My db_connect.php file looks like this (with dummy values for purpose of this post):

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "servername.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "my_database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>
```

My form_page.php form looks like this:

```
    <form id="2017-challenge-form" method="post" data-abide>

        <!-- form fields are here -->

        <input id="btn-submit" type="submit" name="btn-save" value="submit">

    </form>
```

And finally my app.js looks like this:

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    /* handle form submit */
    function submitForm() {
        var data = $("#2017-challenge-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'register.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#error").fadeOut();
                $("#btn-submit").val('Submitting...');
            },
            success : function(response) {
                if(response==1){
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>   Sorry email already taken !</div>');
                    $("#btn-submit").val('Submit');
                });
            } else if(response=="registered"){
                $("#btn-submit").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />   Signing Up ...');
                setTimeout('$(".form-signin").fadeOut(500, function(){ $(".register_container").load("welcome.php"); }); ',3000);
                } else {
                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>   '+data+' !</div>');
                        $("#btn-submit").val('Submit');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#2017-challenge-form").submit(function(event){
        // cancels the form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        // jumps into ajax submit function
        submitForm();
    });

});
```

I have a breakpoint set just inside the ajax success and on submission of  the form I would expect the response to have a value of 'registered' (just like the Demo from the PHPZag site: http://phpzag.com/demo/ajax-registration-script-with-php-mysql-and-jquery/

[image: PHPZag response]

But I get an empty string:
[image: My version]

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong or am missing?

Comment: what a messy post !

Comment: Your HTML does not look correct. The code from the tutorial says `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-save" id="btn-submit">(...)</button>`, but you have `<input id="btn-submit" type="submit" name="btn-save" value="submit"></button>`, you can't mix these elements.

Comment: @DavidJorHpan Yeah I don't post on here too often.

Comment: Where is the action in the form?

Comment: @TomUdding Yes I noticed that a moment ago and removed it. That doesn't make any difference to my issue though but good spot.

Comment: @AliRasheed Should I need the action if I'm using Ajax? The demo doesn't have it but I'm unsure if that's bet practice etc.

Comment: @Damodog hey! remove the `echo` statement in register.php

Comment: @AliRasheed I've removed the echo "in if"; and now get an empty string again but a large empty space in between the "      "?

Comment: Well, want to teamviewer it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142393/discussion-between-damodog-and-ali-rasheed).

Comment: Not your current issue but your SQL is using the wrong quotes, open to SQL injections and `agree_terms` is a string, not a variable.

Comment: @chris85 Good call. I've just read up on mysql_real_escape_string so will use this to be more secure. I just noticed the agree_terms too. Good spot.

    $first_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name'])."';

Comment: @Damodog Escaping is out of date. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Also anything `mysql_` should not be used (and wouldnt work with `mysqli`).

Comment: @chris85 Cheers for that Chris. I don't do a lot in PHP so that's handy to know.

Comment: Do note that according to [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/),  submit will not be serialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the input to a button as per the demo site and this worked. As per the comment by @frz3993 the `btn-save` wasn't getting added to the data so the `if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))` was never true as it wasn't finding it.